# How to remove white space between frame Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I created grids in Xamarin forms like

```
   [![<StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame  HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Margin="20,-40,20,0" Padding="0" HeightRequest="120" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="" FontSize="Large"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label Text=""/>    
                    </StackLayout> 
                </Grid>
        </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Margin="20,-40,20,0" Padding="0" HeightRequest="300" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Gray" >                
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10" Margin="20,-40,20,0" Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Gray">   
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>][1]][1]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHh6d.png): 
[image]

I want to remove this spaces?I am new to Xamarin.So any help.
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You could post in answer and accpet it.

Answer (score 4):

use `Spacing`

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
```

Comment: Ok i found solution i must change verticalOptions to Center